# Use #state with taxonomy reference field (multiple terms)

Tags: forms

If we add a “taxonomy” reference field, we have a field in the form that lists the terms. If I dump `$form`, I get for this field:

```
field_zone" => array:7 [▼
    "#type" => "container"
    "#parents" => array:1 [▶]
    "#attributes" => array:1 [▶]
    "widget" => array:15 [▼
      "#title" => "Zone"
      "#description" => ""
      "#field_parents" => []
      "#required" => false
      "#delta" => 0
      "#weight" => 0
      "#element_validate" => array:1 [▶]
      "#key_column" => "target_id"
      "#type" => "checkboxes"
      "#default_value" => []
      "#options" => array:12 [▼
        433 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6483 ▼
          #string: "Asie-Pacifique"
        }
        434 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6580 ▼
          #string: "-Asie de l’Est"
        }
        10 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6703 ▼
          #string: "Afrique"
        }
        11 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6704 ▼
          #string: "-Afrique de l’Ouest"
        }
        12 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6705 ▼
          #string: "-Afrique Centrale"
        }
        13 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6706 ▶}
        14 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6707 ▶}
        15 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6708 ▶}
        16 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6709 ▶}
        17 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6710 ▶}
        18 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6711 ▶}
        19 => Drupal\Core\Field\FieldFilteredMarkup {#6712 ▶}
      ]
      "#after_build" => array:1 [▶]
      "#field_name" => "field_zone_expertise"
      "#parents" => array:1 [▶]
      "#tree" => true
    ]
```

We can therefore see that the field is of the container type and that each taxonomy term is an option. In front, it appears as checkboxes.

Is it possible to use `#states` with these options? I have tried many things without success.

I know how to do it with a single field but not with this multiple field. I would like when we check on the parent term that the child terms are checked.

I tried to do it with custom JS but I encounter problems when I add the “checked” attribute :

```
$('#edit-field-zone-11').attr('checked', true);
```

It works but not always well because Drupal doesn't use this attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Form `#states` API only works good with plain, native HTML inputs (all kind of text inputs, radios, checkboxes and select). So if you use checkboxes/radios or select as input widget for your taxonomy, it should work as expected. It does not really work well with Javascript widgets like tag-style taxonomy input, [select2](https://www.drupal.org/project/select2) or [chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen)

Background:

Basically form states API is just client-side javascript, that uses CSS selectors to check and set the state of the dependent fields. If the form widget heavily modifies the HTML structure in the browser (like the tag-style taxonomy widget), then the selectors from states API will no longer match with the rendered HTML/CSS in the browser and the states API will not trigger.

States that operate on the field's parenting div-container (visible/hidden) might still work even with JS widgets, states working with/compairing values will most likely fail due the manipulated HTML structure generated by the JS widget.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. After having studied the question well, I think that it is not possible to use `#states` with options of a field.